# The host name in the certificate is invalid - R

Tags: r

For the past four months, I had no problems downloading the zip files from the [Department of Labor](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/ebsa/about-ebsa/our-activities/public-disclosure/foia/form-5500-datasets). Last night, however, when I went to download the data, I received the following error message: 'The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match'.  I tried several different trouble shooting solutions this morning, including changing my default broswer, but nothing seems to work.  I also tried two different computers at different WIFI stations and still receive the same error message.  I'm curious to see if others receive the same error messsage.  Any insight on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#DOWNLOAD_SCHEDULE_A
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://askebsa.dol.gov/FOIA%20Files/2014/Latest/F_SCH_A_2014_Latest.zip",temp)
sch_a <- read.csv(unz(temp, "F_SCH_A_2014_latest.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cld be a misconfiguration on their end or possibly due to slightly outdated CA db files on your end. You can try:

```
library(curl)
curl_download("https://askebsa.dol.gov/FOIA%20Files/2014/Latest/F_SCH_A_2014_Latest.zip",
              temp, handle=new_handle(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE, ssl_verifyhost=FALSE))
```

but note that it's woefully insecure (i.e. subject to in-transit data integrity issues).